# Message boxes in Polymer applications

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am working on my first bigger Polymer application and currently have around 30 components. Most of the components need to be able to display (modal) message boxes. For this I implemented a message box component wrapping paper-dialog (similar to other message box components available).

What I don't like is that in every component which wants to display message boxes I need to define an element

```
<my-message-box id="message-box"></my-message-box>
```

and then call it like this

```
this.$["message-box"].information("Something happened...");
```

This works but my gut feeling is that a message box should be more like a global service, a singleton maybe. In C# f.e. there exists a static method on the MessageBox class.

Is the above mechanism really the recommended way to do it or are there better solutions to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current approach is to create `error-dialog` and add it as a sibling to my `main-app` in `index.html`:

```
<body>
  <main-app></main-app>
  <error-dialog></error-dialog>
  <noscript>
    Please enable JavaScript to view this website.
  </noscript>
</body>
```

`error-dialog`'s `ready()` method adds a custom event:

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
  this.addEventListener('o_error', e => this._errorListener(e));
}

_errorListener(e) {
  this.o_error = e.detail;
  this.$.errorDlog.open();
}
```

Now I can open `error-dialog` from anywhere with

```
let msg = ...
const dlog = document.querySelector('error-dialog');
dlog.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('o_error', {detail: msg, bubbles: true, composed: true}));
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution and it btw seems to solve the stacking context problem https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/7